# Using second hand Skylander games

Tags: skylanders

If I purchase second hand games will they appear to be already played?  like items being found or chests being opened?  If so, is there a way to reset the game back to the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the platform, obviously.

DS games store saves on the cartridge, so you may need to wipe the save on that (there should be an option in the menu). All other platforms will not have any of the saved game.

Pre-owned Skylander character figures will retain their level, etc. so you will need to "claim ownership" of them in the menu when you place them on the portal to reset them.

Comment: The game shops that sell 2nd hand Skylanders around here wipe the data before they put the figures on sale.